# regex basic url expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Hi I'm creating a regular expression (ruby) to test the beginning and end of string. I have both parts but can't join them.

Beginning of string

```
\A(http:\/\/+)
```

End of string

```
(.pdf)\z
```

How to join?
Bonus if it could validate in-between and accept anything (to avoid `http://.pdf`)

By the way, rubular http://rubular.com is a neat place to validate expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.+` to *match any character except \n one or more times.*

```
\A(http:\/\/+).+(\.pdf)\z
```

Should match `http://www.stackoverflow.com/bestbook.pdf` but not `http://.pdf`

Comment: this is a good option if you're sure it's always all or nothing.  it won't match `http://.pdf` but it will match `http://foo.pdf`or even `http:///.pdf` basically as long as there is at least one character between the `/` and the `.` it will still pass.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant to escape the `.` in `.pdf`. Also, the grouping is unnecessary as well as the `+` after `\/\/`. No -1 though because I'm feeling generous.